# Finding the best combination of numbers from a list

Tags: dynamic-programming

Example data:

```
A = a set of 'things' denoted by integers {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
B = value of "something" at each integer {23,33,54,12,45,66,21,23,44,77}
distance = the required distance between integers; 
//i.e. if distance = 2, you could choose 0 and 2 but not 1 and 2 - since (2 - 1 < 2)

So, AT 0, the value = 23
AT 1, the value = 33
```

Since it seems like I am being very clear in my head... but to no one else let me try to explain the problem better:

```
A = the 1 foot intervals from the start to the end.
B = the dollar amount you can pick up at a given interval
distance = the minimum distance you can travel between intervals.
```

So, if you pick up $23 at the start, you would have to skip the $33 at interval 1. Then you can pick up the $54 at interval 2.

I think, you have to choose the best $$$ at each interval.

So the best of 0,1 then the best at 2,3 etc. (whatever the distance may be)

but maybe not... because if 1 is the best in the first, and 2 is the best in the second the "best" method fails..

Comment: Your question is not making any sense . Please re-phrase .

Comment: "value of each integer"?  Doesn't each integer already *have* a value?

Comment: @scott, changes it to be AT that integer, bad phrasing, and the 0 1 was meant to be 0 2. That was a typo.

Comment: Three problems: **1.** You are defining a distance, but your are not using it. **2.** You want a combination of integers, but how many integers exactly? **3.** `A` is an array containing the indexes of the elements in `B`. Is it really useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I am using the below equation for computing the opt value in the dynamic programming:

```
if (i -d) >= 0
opt(i) = max (opt(i-1), B[i] + OPT(i-d));

else 

opt(i) = max (opt(i-1), B[i]);
```

Psuedo-code for computing the OPT value:

```
int A[] = {integers list}; // This is redundant if the integers are consecutive and are always from 0..n.
int B[] = {values list};
int i = 0;
int d = distance; // minimum distance between two picks.
int numIntegers = sizeof(A)/sizeof(int);

int opt[numIntegers];

opt[0] = B[0]; // For the first one Optimal value is picking itself.
for (i=1; i < numIntegers; i++) {

    if ((i-d) < 0) {
        opt[i] = max (opt[i-1], B[i]);
    } else {
        opt[i] = max (opt[i-1], B[i] + opt[i-d]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Now, what if I want to add the corresponding integers to a separate list to signify that they were the ones used for the total?

For example, if 1, 3, 5 were the $$ chosen to make the max, how can i capture that?